# How do I use JQ to flatten JSON-lines where each is an array into an item-per-line?

Tags: json, jq

I have the JSON as at bottom. If I send it to `jq '.a[].b` I get

```
[
  "x1",
  "x2"
]
[
  "y1",
  "y2"
]
```

How do I instead get line-by-line output, no brackets, quotes, or commas, like this:

```
x1
x2
y1
y2
```

The input JSON is:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": [
        "x1",
        "x2"
      ],
      "z": "z"
    },
    {
      "b": [
        "y1",
        "y2"
      ],
      "w": "w"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same thing with each `b` that you did with each `a`. Use the `-r` option to get the raw text, rather than JSON string values.

```
% jq -r '.a[].b[]' tmp.json
x1
x2
y1
y2
```

That is, `.b` outputs the list; `.b[]` outputs each element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, attempts you could try following `jq` code also. Using `-r` option of `jq` to send input in raw form. Then appropriately getting values as per requirement here.

```
jq -r '(.[] | .[].b)[]'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
x1
x2
y1
y2
```